# XeLaTeX can't find any packages (PdfLaTeX works)

Tags: xetex, pdftex, packages, texlive, texstudio

I'm currently trying to build a document with XeLaTeX because I need it for a template. My OS is Scientific Linux 7.2 and I use texlive + Texstudio as an editor.

Now the problem that I have is that whenever I try to compile with XeLaTex, none of my installed packages are found, e.g. braket, bbm, nccmath, ....
However, if I compile with PdfLaTeX all packages are found.
According to 'tlmgr list --only-installed' all of these packages are properly installed.

Do I need to kind of 'register' the packages in XeLaTeX, or why doesn't it find anything? Feels like a dumb question, but I haven't found anything on google or stackexchange.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The obvious next step: what does `xelatex` (the command) from the commnd line manage to find? Next compare `which pdflatex` and `which xelatex`.

Comment: Welcome! If things are as described, then something is very wrong with your TeX installation. Providing the exact error message generated when you compile a minimal document and including the code of that document here would enable people to say something more helpful.

Comment: Perhaps it might be your choice of Linux and the way its security may be set up.  I know that texlive works very predictably on a Debian based or Redhat\Fedora based install.  Unless you really need to use Scientific Linux another choice might ease installation problems.  Of course, if you are running something along the lines of the Large Hadron Collider...

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, I couldn't make it earlier. 
@Jon: xelatex output is the following: pastebin.com/hyb8Bprw 
Which pdlatex: /usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-linux/pdflatex
Which xelatex: /usr/bin/xelatex
Maybe that's the problem? tlmgr said that xetex is already installed, so I also tried it with a yum install. The path for xetex is not correct, I guess?

Comment: @cfr
This is the logfile, it basically just says that the package isn't found: http://pastebin.com/29PBsTi2
The code already stops at the amsmath package: http://pastebin.com/2FACLz73

A Feldman: I have no other choice than using Scientific Linux, because as you said LHC kind of things.

Comment: I installed texlive with './install-tl'. Does it install all packages, or should I have added an all command? I was following this guide: http://astr.tohoku.ac.jp/~akhlaghi/newlinux.html
That's why I didn't pay attention.

Comment: You have 2 installations of TeX. This is the problem. One is installed with your Linux distro's package manager, I assume (`yum`/`dnf`). The other is from upstream (`install-tl`). You need to decide which you want to keep and remove the other. If you want to keep upstream's, you need to take some steps to convince `yum`/`dnf` that TeX Live is installed. Although a bit more complex initially, this is the recommended option and often more straightforward overall.

Comment: Basically, you install a 'dummy' package which tells `yum`/`dnf` that TL is installed so that you can install software which depends on TL without your distro installing its own copy, which leads to problems. The dummy package is designed to satisfy the dependencies of software which needs TL such as editors and so on.

Comment: [This question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu?s=8|1.3017) is the most helpful on this. Although it talks about Debian-based installs, the issues are the same and it can be easily modified for other Linux distros. (For example, Fedora-based installs using `yum`/`dnf` rather than `apt`, Arch Linux using `pacman` and so on.)

Comment: It is almost certain that you have two different 'TeX systems' installed. You need to decide which to keep (or make active by default). It is a `path` problem. I'd be inclined to purge both installs and install only one of them.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer: I solved the problem by just setting the correct texlive path in my editor TeXStudio (the tlmgr one and not the yum installed one). 

Thank you all very much!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved in comments